# How can make video file from images of 1 image per second using ffmpeg?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

we are creaing video from images  using ffmpeg on window. The video is created successfully but we are not able to control number of images per second of video. we need 2 images per second in video.

Below is code we used

```
exec('ffmpeg -y -f image2 -framerate 2 -i C:/inetpub/wwwroot/movie/images/%d.jpg video60.mpg', $output, $exit_status);
```

Please help us to find solution for above problem.

Comment: MPG codecs support a limited set of framerates.

Comment: which format to use for 1 or 2 images per second in video?

Comment: MP4 using `-pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264`